# How to do group by chunk wise in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've following table, My_Table, with structure as follows,

```
Name   | Address
----------------
Test1  | abc
Test1  | abc
Test2  | abc
Test1  | xyz
Test2  | abc
Test3  | abc
Test4  | tyu
```

I need output as follows,

```
Name   | Address
----------------
Test2  | abc
Test3  | abc
```

Let me explain you the output. The output is grouping data in chunks and if second column has all the grouped data based on Name is same and it is equal to `abc` then select that row.

**Explanation in detail:**
Test1 has 2 distinct values and one of them is not equal to `abc`, hence it is not in output. Test2 and Test3 has one distinct value and it is equal to `abc`, hence in output. Test4 has one distinct but it is not equal to `abc`, hence not in output.

What I've tried,

```
all = select distinct(Name) from My_Table
invalid = select distinct(Name) from My_Table where Address != 'abc'
```

Now, **desired output is `all - invalid` (subtracting result set)**. I achieved this using 2 queries. can this be achieved in one query? If yes, how?

**Note**: I'm using JAVA for query MYSQL DB, hence I can subtract result sets. My table size is huge, hence I want to **optimize number of queries**!

Comment: Your explanation of the output doesn't help me understand what you are doing.  Can you provide more details on why those two rows are chosen?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added more details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, max(address)
from tablename
group by name
having max(address) = min(address)
   and max(address) = 'abc'
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and get back :)