# How to do group by chunk wise in SQL with negative condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34065902/3906965). Now, I need reverse output of it. I've following table, My_Table, with structure as follows,

```
Name   | Address
----------------
Test1  | abc_123
Test1  | abc_456
Test2  | xyz_123
Test1  | xyz_123
Test2  | xyz_456
Test3  | abc_123
Test4  | xyz_123
Test1  | xyz_456
Test3  | xyz_123
Test4  | xyz_456
```

I need output as follows,

```
Name   
-------
Test2 
Test4
```

I need to do group by chunkwise and select the `Name`, such that none of the address has prefix as `abc`.

**Output Explanation in detail**:

Test1 has addresses as `abc_123, abc_456, xyz_123, abc_123` and at least one of the address has prefix as `abc`. Hence not in output.
Test2 is has addresses as `xyz_123, xyz_456` and  none of them has prefix `abc`. Hence in output.

```
x = select distinct(Name) from My_Table
y = select distinct(Name) from My_Table where Address like 'abc%'

Result  = x - y
```

I was able to achieve result using 2 queries (as shown above) and then using subtract operation in the result set, but can this be achieved in **single query**?

**Note:** I'm using JAVA for query MYSQL DB, hence I can subtract result sets. My table size is huge, hence I want to **optimize number of queries**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses aggregation and is similar to the other answer:

```
select name
from my_table
group by name
having sum(address like 'abc%') = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of matching rows.  The `= 0` says there are none for a given name.

Comment: Awesome! Now, I feel stupid as I couldn't think of the aggregation thing. I'll mark it as answer after trying it ;)